# PHP SQL - Inserting into a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, insert

I have a problem dear stackoverflowers, could someone please help me out?

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "password";
    $db   = "hotelcalifornia";

    $room_Number      = ($_POST['Room_Number']);
    $room_Category    = ($_POST['Room_Category']);
    $room_Description = ($_POST['Room_Description']);
    $room_Detail      = ($_POST['Room_Detail']);

    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    $db   = mysql_select_db($db, $conn);

    mysql_select_db($db, $conn);

    $sql = "INSERT TO room (roomNumber, roomCategory, roomDescription,roomDetail) VALUES ('$room_Number','$room_Category', '$room_Description','$room_Detail')";

    mysql_query($sql, $conn);        

?>
```

Can someone tell me why i can't insert this data into my table in the database?

Comment: why are you using `mysql_select_db` twice? and using `$db` could have adverse effects. There's probably more going on that you don't know neither.

Comment: I posted the old code, but the problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It's not `INSERT TO`, it's `INSERT INTO`.Thus you shouldn't use mysql functions, instead use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions as your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "password";
$db   = "hotelcalifornia";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

$room_Number      = $_POST['Room_Number'];
$room_Category    = $_POST['Room_Category'];
$room_Description = $_POST['Room_Description'];
$room_Detail      = $_POST['Room_Detail'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO room (roomNumber, roomCategory, roomDescription,roomDetail) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('iiss', $room_Number, $room_Category, $room_Description, $room_Detail);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    if($stmt->affected_rows > 0){
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $stmt->error;
}
$stmt->close();
```

Within the line `$stmt->bind_param('iiss', $room_Number, $room_Category, $room_Description, $room_Detail);` `i` corresponds to the integer where `s` corresponds to string by the order of the variables, which I assume `$room_Number` and `$room_Category` are integer values where `$room_Description` and `$room_Detail` are string values.

Comment: Sidenote: As per your edit and using `mysqli_`, doesn't protect against injection, prepared statements do. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: yeah, gotta update soon again, thanks.

Comment: 2nd sidenote: `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {` isn't the best method to make sure that the db was successfully queried, `affected_rows` does http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php which is what should always be used.